# DateTime2 to C# DateTime with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqldatareader, datetime2

I realize this might be a dupe, but I've spent hours searching for the answer and can't seem to find it.

I'm currently creating a web API that retrieves concert data.

I have a SQL Server table that holds a start and end date, both as a `datetime2` type. I've inserted the dates in this format and they don't cause any problems when viewing the database:

```
2015-10-08T20:00:00.0000000+01:00
```

My model:

```
public class Concert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And my method in the class that brings up my database data:

```
    public List<Concert> getAll() 
    {
        List<Concert> concerts = new List<Concert>();

        SqlConnection connection = CasWebAPIdb.getConnection();
        String selectAll = "SELECT ConcertId, ConcertName, ConcertLocationId FROM dbo.Concerts";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectAll, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            var isoDateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("lol: " + reader["ConcertEnd"].GetType());

                Concert concert = new Concert();

                concert.Id = (int)reader["ConcertId"];
                concert.Name = reader["ConcertName"].ToString();
                concert.LocationId = (int)reader["ConcertLocationId"];
                concert.Start = (DateTime)reader["ConcertStart"];
                concert.End = (DateTime)reader["ConcertEnd"];

                concerts.Add(concert);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return concerts;
    }
}
```

I get this error when debugging:

> An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

I have tried a lot of things and followed a lot of examples and codes, but I can't seem to convert this properly. Does anybody have an idea?

**solution**

I forgot to add the 'concertStart' and 'concertEnd' to my query. 
Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ConcertStart"])` instead of casting ?

Comment: it wouldn't make much difference there by doing a cast or a convert. you have not specified exactly what the problem is? It should work as the DateTime and DateTime2 data type of SQL map to Datetime in .NET

Comment: When you say that you can't seem to convert it properly, how did you determine that? What is the result that you expect, and what result do you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, if you want to read the value of `ConcertStart` and `ConcertEnd`, you'd have to **include them** in your `SELECT`!!$

```
string selectAll = @"SELECT ConcertId, ConcertName, ConcertLocationId,
                            ConcertStart, ConcertEnd     <<--- add these!! 
                     FROM dbo.Concerts";
```

Try this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Concert concert = new Concert();

    concert.Id = (int)reader["ConcertId"];
    concert.Name = reader["ConcertName"].ToString();
    concert.LocationId = (int)reader["ConcertLocationId"];
    concert.Start = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(reader.GetOrdinal("ConcertStart"));
    concert.End = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(reader.GetOrdinal("ConcertEnd"));

    concerts.Add(concert);
}
```

I have no trouble **at all** reading out a `DATETIME2(3)` value from the SQL Server database using

```
reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(reader.GetOrdinal("ConcertEnd"));
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: My god, I'm such an idiot. Adding the dates to the query was all it took.

You're a lifesaver.

Comment: @Daemun: sometimes all it takes is just another pair of eyes :-)

Comment: how do we get only the date for this? like remove the 12:00:00 appended at the end?

Comment: In .NET - use the `.Date` property on the `DateTime` datatype; in T-SQL - use `CAST(column AS DATE)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your select, you only return 3 of the columns needed:

```
 String selectAll = "SELECT ConcertId, ConcertName, ConcertLocationId ...";
```

Whereas in your reader, you attempt to scrape 5 columns:

```
concert.Id = (int)reader["ConcertId"];
concert.Name = reader["ConcertName"].ToString();
concert.LocationId = (int)reader["ConcertLocationId"];
concert.Start = (DateTime)reader["ConcertStart"];
concert.End = (DateTime)reader["ConcertEnd"];
```

Hence the `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Either select all columns, or remove the extraneous ones from the reader.

The issue isn't related to Sql `DateTime2` vs .Net `DateTime` - ADO will bind these just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with an extension method I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692603/Csharp-String-Extensions)

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this string input, bool throwExceptionIfFailed = false)
{
    DateTime result;
    var valid = DateTime.TryParse(input, out result);
    if (!valid)
        if (throwExceptionIfFailed)
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("'{0}' cannot be converted as DateTime", input));
   return result;
}
```

Convert your data like this:

```
concert.Start = reader["ConcertStart"].ToString().ToDate();
concert.End = reader["ConcertEnd"].ToString().ToDate(true); //throws an exception if it fails
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who wants to restore SQL DateTime2 to DateTime correctly including `'Kind=Utc'`

```
(DateTime)reader["ConcertEnd"].ToUniversalTime();
```

otherwise DateTime may struggle to workout what timezone the date is from